# Rails has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A company has many locations (Location has company_id column). A location has many items and an item has many locations (join table).

company.rb

```
has_many :locations
```

location.rb

```
belongs_to :company
has_many :items, through: :item_locations
has_many :item_locations, :dependent => :destroy
```

item.rb

```
has_many :item_locations, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :locations, through: :item_locations
```

item_location.rb

```
belongs_to :item
belongs_to :location
```

Can I retrieve all items for a company, without adding company_id to Item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just change your `Company` relationships to:

```
has_many :locations
has_many :item_locations, through: :locations
has_many :items, through: :item_locations
```

This should let you call `company.items`